# phonegap ios simulator weird behavior with ontouchstart event

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, ios-simulator

I'm coding on phonegap, and met weird behavior with `ontouchstart` event in ios simulator.

Here is how i detect what event i should use (project also have to work on PC browsers):

```
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
    var eventType = 'touchstart';
} else {
    var eventType = 'click';
}
```

IOS simulator detects `eventType` as `touchstart`, it is ok. 
Using next code, i am listening event, and after event is fired, i am doing some stuff like in below code:

```
$('#elId').bind(eventType, function() {
    // ... some stuff
});
```

Seems everything HAVE TO work ok, but it not works =(

The most weird thing, all of this works, if i just append this code:

```
$(document).bind(eventType, function() {
    // ... empty body
})
```

or set `eventType = click` always.

What can be a problem?

PS: i'm using iOS Simulator Version 6.0 (369.2)

Comment: Without seeing your markup it is hard to say, but you could have element inside of `#elId` that are intercepting or canceling the touch event.

Comment: @lemieuxster markup is pretty simple. i checked inside elements, and no one prevents event. The most weird thing what makes me confused, why does it works if i put code where i listen same event for document object, before eventlistener code for `#elId` =(